# Conditional output

Tags: c++, iostream

I'd like to create a C++ ostream object that only outputs anything if a condition holds true, to use for debugging. What would be the easiest way to do this? I know that boost has classes that make this easy, but I'd like to know if there's a simple way to do it without boost. The documentation makes it seem like subclassing ostream::sentry would make this possible, but I can't find any source saying that's something that you can/should do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't subclass, it's easier to use a wrapper:

```
class MaybeOstream
{
public:
    MaybeOstream(std::ostream& stream_) : stream(stream_), bOutput(true) {}

    void enable(bool bEnable) { bOutput = bEnable; }

    template<typename T>
    MaybeOstream& operator<< (T x)
    {
        if(bOutput)
            stream << x;
        return *this;
    }

    // Add other wrappers around ostream: operator void*, good(), fail(),
    // eof(), etc., which just call through to the ostream

private:
    std::ostream& stream;
    bool bOutput;
}
```

Comment: This would require a test of the condition (if the condition could change at any time) and a call to your `enable` every time the stream was going to be used. In this case one could just use an `if` before every output.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I didn't know you could do that with templates. Is it some kind of type inference? What terms should I search to find out more? (And pointing out a minor typo to others who may find this answer useful: stream(stream) should be stream(stream_). Had me scratching my head when it segfaulted.)

edit @JohnPS I intend to use this basically for debug logging type situations so the condition will be global state. The code that prints doesn't care whether the condition's false because it's set elsewhere.

Comment: which boost class does this job?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this paper](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/att-49459/fltrsbf1.htm) on filtered streambufs.